# Parse on Buddy.com, push notifications sent via API not delivered

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, buddy.com

I've almost successfully migrated an existing app from Parse.com to Buddy.com for sending and receiving push notifications.

Registering, acquiring the deviceToken, and subscribing to channels works. I can see the installation details in the data Browser and also sending push notifications directly from the Dashboard works. Notifications are received almost immediately in the app.

Now I have changed my server application (using the Parse PHP-SDK 1.2.1) to use the Buddy API endpoint and configured it to use the masterkey for authentication. Although sending a push notification via the API doesn't give an error and is even returning "result => 1", notifications are never received in the application. I can't find a server log like on the original Parse Dashboard at Buddy, so I can't verify if the messages I sent are really queued and picked up for delivery.

I'm a missing something essential?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Seems that the Parse.com api accepted push data payload in JSON encoded format. But for the Buddy.com platform, data should be passed as plain array.

My payload as I pull it from our notification queue:

```
$data = '{"alert":"Test bericht"}';
```

Although returning result => true, this won't work:

```
ParsePush::send(array(
  "channels" => ['user_1234'],
  "data" => $data
), true);
```

This works as expected:

```
ParsePush::send(array(
  "channels" => ['user_1234'],
  "data" => json_decode($data, true)
), true);
```